# T-SQL: do I need a stored procedure for dynamic string to work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make this code work, ...

```
SELECT *
FROM UserInGroup

DECLARE @SqlQuery nvarchar(500),
    @userIds nvarchar(50),
    @GroupId nvarchar(50);

SET @userIds = '1, 2';
SET @SqlQuery = 
            'INSERT INTO UserInGroup
            (GroupId, UserId)
            SELECT ' + @GroupId + ', UserId
            FROM [User]
            WHERE UserId IN ('+ @userIds +')';

EXECUTE @SqlQuery
GO

SELECT *
FROM UserInGroup
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 16
>   Could not find stored procedure ''.

I've tried to put this in a stored procedure, but I'm getting nothing.

Comment: show the whole code of your SP and how you call it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the way you execute

```
EXECUTE @SqlQuery to ->> Exec (@SqlQuery)
```

You might find it in detail here about [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your method is subject to SQL Injection. You need to use parametrised sp_executesql or use user defined table-valued function and join with it to get the data

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or newer I would encourage you to use a table valued parameter that you could join on the user table. Then you would not need any dynamic SQL. More on that **[here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html#TVP_in_TSQL)**.

Then your procedure might look something like this:

```
Create procedure myBrandNewProcedureUsingTableValuedParameters
    @userIds myCustomTableType readonly,
    @GroupId nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO UserInGroup
  (GroupId, UserId)
  SELECT  @GroupId, [User].UserId
  FROM [User]
  INNER JOIN
  @userIds as u
  on [User].UserID = u.UserID
END
```